# React Routes are not functioning well over LOGOUT?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am working on a project where i need to integrate Auth functionality, but i counter with a redirection issue. after Logout i am not landing over **/auth**, it still resides on **/dashboard** component, but if I refresh the the page it redirects to the **/auth** component.

> Testing Scenario:

1. once **loge In**, then same time **Logout**, it will work fine, will take you to the **/auth**
2. once **Log In**, type in the url **auth**, it will redirect to the Dashboard same time, which is absolutely fine. but after this, if you try to **logout**, it will **logout**, but the url will not redirect to **auth**.

> Logout Functionality

```
const logout = () => {
    dispatch({type: actionTypes.LOGOUT})
    history.push('/auth')
    setUserProfile(null)
}
```

> Logout Reducer

```
import { AUTH, LOGOUT, LOGIN_CODE } from '../constants/ActionTypes'
const authReducer = (state={authData: null}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGOUT:
        localStorage.removeItem("userProfile")
        return {...state, authData: null}
    default:
        return state
  }
}
export default authReducer
```

> Routes

```
<switch>
    <Route path="/" component={()=> <Redirect to="/dashboard" />} exact />
    <PrivateRoute path="/" component={Dashboard} auth={user} exact />
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} auth={user} exact />
    <PublicRoute path="/auth" component={Login} auth={user} restricted={true} exact />
<swtich>
```

> PrivateRoute Code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
const PrivateRoute = ({component : Component, auth, ...rest})=>{
return(
    <Route {...rest} render={props =>{
        if(!auth)
            return <Redirect to="/auth"/>
        return <Component {...props}/>
    }}/>
 )
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

> PublicRoute Code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PublicRoute = ({auth, component: Component, restricted, ...rest}) => {
   return (
       // restricted = false meaning public route
       // restricted = true meaning restricted route
       <Route {...rest} render={props => (
         auth && restricted ?
            <Redirect to="/" />
            : <Component {...props} />
       )} />
     );
    };
 export default PublicRoute;
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched every possible solution to fix this uncertain behavior of **react-router-dom**, but did not find any logical solution for this. but now at the end I came up with the hot fix for this type of issue. just need to add the *tiny one line* snippet in **logout** functionality. which I mentioned below for best reference.

> reload route after **logOut**

```
window.location.reload()
```

this function will not hold the component and url too. once **logout** functionality run, will redirect to the **auth** route right away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import Router from 'next/router'

Then after logout send:

Router.reload();

Answer (score 0):

You must Call function localStorage when you logout:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

it will redirect you into your auth page.

Comment: it is already done. in logout functionality

Comment: call user function into useEffect

  useEffect(() => {
   logout()
  }, []);

Comment: no man it will not work like that. this functionality will continue login Out the user.